# angular ngResource post data not accepted by laravel 5 input or request

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5, ngresource

the problem is I can not get the post data by

```
Input::all()
```

or

```
Request::all()
```

I've checked the right class is imported;

```
use Request;
use Input;
```

However I can get the data this way;

```
$request = Request::instance();
$content = $request->getContent();
var_dump($content);
```

But I certainly need the Input and Request working instead.

Comment: Is the content json?

Comment: Input expects posted form data.  Not the same.

Comment: I take it back.  The L4 manual says json is fine with Input.  The L5 does not and there is some discussion.  Have you tried Request::json()?

Comment: the json() method works. thank you!